# Symfony2, Twig, change twig after include

Tags: symfony, block, twig

I have such hierarchy of twig files

my main (for controller) twig

```
{% extends "MainSiteBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block footer_moderator_buttons %}
    some buttons
{% endblock %}

{% block content_body %}
    <p>hello moderator</p>

    {{ include ('MainBlogBundle:_parts:postList.html.twig', {'postList': aPostDraft}) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**postList.html.twig**

```
<div class="post-list">
{% for postSingle in postList %}
    {{ include ('MainBlogBundle:_parts:postSingle.html.twig', {'postSingle': postSingle}) }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**postSingle.html.twig**

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-header">
        <a class="title" href="3">{{ postSingle.title }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post-meta">
        <div>Date: {{ postSingle.date|date('D M Y') }}</div>
        <div>Category: <a href="#">{{ postSingle.getCategory.getTitle }}</a></div>
        <div>Author: <a href="#">{{ postSingle.getUser.username }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-body">
        <div class="content">
            <img width="450" height="200" src="#">
            <div class="text">{{ postSingle.content }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-footer">
        {% block footer_moderator_buttons %}f{% endblock %}
        <div>Views: 152</div>
        <div>Comments: 1231</div>
        <div>
            <a class="link" href="#">More... </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see last (postSingle.html.twig) has block "footer_moderator_buttons", ***so how can i change it from main twig*** (first one) ? Current is not working, what I need change \ do ?

Comment: you wanna on f to some buttons?

Comment: no matter, i want fill in block footer_moderator_buttons from main twig

Comment: I think can't create block inside partial template that are included, or it's not logical ! Also, this are contained in a loop, how Twig is able to understand multiple time the same block name "footer_moderator_buttons" that is suppose to be unique like an id ?!

Comment: Ditto what @Sybio said, it's illogical to do their other way round. What are you achieving? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: yes, another way exist, but i want to understand how\what twig can, ok lets say we cannot do this way, so how you will do the logic for viewing posts using twig, but postList.html.twig and postSingle.html.twig must be standalone files (not all in one) because postList and postSingle i'm going use a LOT of times

Answer (score 1):

In Twig 1.8 there is `embed` tag (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html).

You would have to remove the `postList.html.twig` file or work around it.

```
{% embed "MainBlogBundle:_parts:postSingle.html.twig" with {'postSingle': postSingle} %}
    {% block footer_moderator_buttons %}
        custom buttons here
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you question is actually "I want to understand how\what twig can". Well, the answer to that question is: "It can't overwrite blocks from "main" to the smaller ones."

If you want to use twig, you have to stop thinking in php include() way where you make new files and you "PUT" components in them over and over again, components such as header, footer, menu etc.

In twig, you define main twig file with blocks which can be imagined as empty spaces which can, but do not have to, be overwritten. Surely, it still means you can have postList.html.twig as include in some file that extends MainSiteBundle::layout.html.twig. The same goes for postSingle.html.twig.

I think you catch the logic of twig except don't try to overwrite blocks from the wrong side - in this case, from MainSiteBundle::layout.html.twig to it's smaller portions.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
{% extends "MainSiteBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
....
{% block footer_moderator_buttons %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

woops didnt put parent..
the {{ parent() }} will inherit {% block footer_moderator_buttons %}{% endblock %} from extended twig.